# Help required with subspace basis

Tags: linear-algebra

I have been around this a couple times, and I haven't been able to fully understand this. Happens that I solved a space basis problem in my linear algebra course but I (and apparently anyone I have asked to) don't really get to understand what the result means. My question is, why the last row is a zero row? I understood something about a basis only spanning a three-dimensional subspace, but no more. Does that mean the fourth coordinate of each vector expressed as linear combination of the basis vector will always be zero such that the vector be in the subspace, or it doesn't work like that ?

So I'm going to provide a detailed explanation about the process I did (which is verified), and highlight the answer I got so someone could answer my question.

The problem is the following:

> S = {**v**<sub>1</sub>, **v**<sub>2</sub>, **v**<sub>3</sub>, **v**<sub>4</sub>, **v**<sub>5</sub>} where:
> **v**<sub>1</sub> = (1, 1, 0, -1) ; **v**<sub>2</sub> = (0, 1, 2, 1) ; **v**<sub>3</sub> = (1, 0, 1, -1) ; **v**<sub>4</sub> = (1, 1, -6, -3) ; **v**<sub>5</sub> = (-1, -5, 1, 0).
> Find a base for the subspace W = span S.

Hence the way I learnt to find out if it was linearly independent and a spanning set was using Gauss-Jordan elimination. So here is my process:

$$
\begin{matrix}
1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & -1 & 0 & a \\
1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & -5 & 0 & b \\
0 & 2 & 1 & -6 & 1 & 0 & c \\
-1 & 1 & -1 & -3 & 0 & 0 & d \\
\end{matrix}
$$

**.
.
.**

$$
\begin{matrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 3 & -4 & 0 & (a + 2b - c)/3 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & -2 & -1 & 0 & (-a + b + c)/3 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & -2 & 3 & 0 & (2a - 2b + c)/3 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & (4a - b - c + 3d)/3 \\
\end{matrix}
$$

Here, I know the first three column vectors where the main entries are represent the basis for the supspace W = span S, it means, the vectors {**v**<sub>1</sub>, **v**<sub>2</sub>, **v**<sub>3</sub>}. So I tried to check if both of the conditions for a basis were fulfilled for the found basis.

$$
\begin{matrix}
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & a \\
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & b \\
0 & 2 & 1 & 0 & c \\
-1 & 1 & -1 & 0 & d \\
\end{matrix}
$$

**.
.
.**

\begin{matrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & (a + 2b - c)/3 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & (-a + b + c)/3 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & (2a - 2b + c)/3 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & (4a - b - c + 3d)/3 \\
\end{matrix}

As you can see, the last row is a zero row. I was expecting something like that due to the dimensions of the matrix. The thing I haven't yet understood is: i) why that row is a zero row? ii) Is it a basis or not? iii) In case it'd be a basis, does the fourth coordinate always has to be zero so a vector expressed as a linear combination of the basis vectors be contained in W? iv) does that mean that as W is 'embedded' in S, some vectors expressed as a linear combination of the basis vectors which fourth coordinate is not zero, the vector is in S but not in W?

I have a lot of questions about this, and I'm basically new in this topic, so I would appreciate so much someone who could easily explain this to me. Thank you.

Comment: For i) The row space and column space always have the same dimension. For ii) basis vectors are non-zero

Comment: Very obviously, $(1,0,0,0), (0,1,0,0), (0,0,1,0)$ do not form a basis for $W=\text{span}(S)$. Why is that obvious? Because four of the five vectors in $S$ have non-zero 4th coordinates, but no linear combination of the supposed basis vectors can ever give you a non-zero 4th coordinate. I do not understand your process. Why do you include the $0$ column? It seems pointless to me. And the orientation is wrong. Row operations are combining coordinates of the same vector, not combining vectors, as you need to do to find a basis.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Never said (1,0,0,0),(0,1,0,0),(0,0,1,0) form a basis for W = span S. Gauss-Jordan is only used to determine if the found basis is linearly independent, as the only way to get the zero vector as a linear combination of the basis vectors is if and only if all the constants are equal to zero. Also, row reduction is used here to determine if those three vectors can span the full space, that's why I wrote it next to the zero vector as a, b, c, d. As I said, I'm new to this topic and I may be wrong, but I'm so sure you need to re-read because you didn't get anything of what I wrote.